# NGRX Store - Create multiple instance of one model

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have ngrx/store up and running, and I am getting my head around it. I can create an action and a reducer to store data based from a model, however when I go to create a second instance of one inside state, it simply adds a new line to my existing state:

Reducer.ts

```
import * as orderhead from '../_actions/orderhead';
import { OrderHead } from '../_models/index';
// Set State to mimic that of the OrderHead model

export interface State {
  orderID: string[];
  entryDate: string[];
  requireDate: string[];
  headerRef: string[];
  pirotity: string[];
};

// Set initial state to empty
const initialState: State = {
  orderID: [],
  entryDate: [],
  requireDate: [],
  headerRef: [],
  pirotity: [],
};


export function OHreducer(state = initialState, action: orderhead.Actions):  State{
      switch (action.type) {
        case orderhead.ActionTypes.CREATE_OH:
            // Create a new instance of the model OrderHead and store it 
            // all other aspects of the model will be updated by other actions
            const order = [...state.orderID, action.payload.orderID]
            return Object.assign({}, state,  {orderID: order})

    }
}
```

And some code to populate the store with some data:

```
createOrderHead(orderid){     
  this._store.dispatch({type: orderhead.ActionTypes.CREATE_OH, payload: {orderID: orderid} });
}
```

Now if I run:

```
createOrderHead('ABC123')
createOrderHead('DEF456')
```

What I get is:

```
{  orderhead: {
    orderID: [
      'ABC123',
      'DEF456'
    ],
    entryDate: [],
    requireDate: [],
    headerRef: [],
    pirotity: []
  }
}
```

However, what I am after is:

```
{  orderhead: [
  {
    orderID:  'ABC123',
    entryDate: [],
    requireDate: [],
    headerRef: [],
    pirotity: []
  },
  {
    orderID:  'DEF456',
    entryDate: [],
    requireDate: [],
    headerRef: [],
    pirotity: []
  }
}]
}
```

I have tried to take some adapation from the sample app provided, but at present I am not able to extract what I need from it in order to find a solution, if someone would be able to let me know what part of my code needs to change in order for this to work, that would be great.

I did try resting state at the start of the reducer, but this obviously just wipes it clean each time its called, destroying previous data.

Update Working,:

So I have updated my reducer, as suggested I needed to create an empty array inside state, and then modify my return statement, working reducer:

```
import { OrderHead } from '../_models/index';
// Set state to  that of imported model
export interface State {
  orders : OrderHead[]
};

// Set initial state to empty
const initialState: State = {
  orders : []
};

export function OHreducer(state = initialState, action: orderhead.Actions):  State{
      switch (action.type) {
        case orderhead.ActionTypes.CREATE_OH:
            // Map payload to instance of array
            const order = [...state.orders, action.payload]
            // Assign the order to the array
            return Object.assign({}, state,  {orders: order})
    }
}
```

Comment: The JSON in your last snippet does not appear to be valid.

Comment: It was just as an example to show I wanted an array of the instance orderhead inside state, I have now updated to valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should need to change your state to an array of orders. Then add the orders to the array.

```
import * as orderhead from '../_actions/orderhead';
import { OrderHead } from '../_models/index';
// Set State to mimic that of the OrderHead model


export interface Order {
    orderID: string | null;
    entryDate: string | null;
    requireDate: string | null;
    headerRef: string | null;
    pirotity: string | null;
  }

export interface State {
  orders : Order[]
};

// Set initial state to empty
const initialState: State = {
  orders : []
};
```

Comment: This just replaces the old state value with the new value, it doesn't create two instances of OrderHead in State

Comment: @crooksey I edit my answer... Try to create a array of orders I think it's the right way to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks that would seem logical, however I cannot do: "const order = [...state.orders.orderID, action.payload.orderID]" as it throws the error "orderID does not exist on type Order[]" when I know it does. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, thats what my initial question showed (working example) but not when using an array inside state.

Comment: I did need to use an array, I also have to update my reducer code accordingly, I have now updated my initial question to show a working answer, thanks for the pointer